# How to change size of editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor, fof

I am trying to change size of editor

Code :-

```
<field name="description" type="editor"
        class="editor"
        label="COM_CPEVENT_TITLE_DESCRIPTION"
        labelclass="cpevent-label cpevent-label-main"
        required="true"
        rows="5" 
        cols="5" 
        filter="raw"
     />
```

I tried `width="40%"` add `height="40%"` but it's not working.

Also tried changing `rows` and `cols` but it's not working.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried to change rows and cols??

Comment: yes @Joomler But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plugin section search for **Editor - TinyMCE**

and then go to the Advance setting and there you will see the **height** and **width** parameters.

Just change it from there and you are done.

Comment: Now I can change `height` but not `width`.

Comment: you can, give the value for width like `200px`, I just tested it